# Chain requests in AWS API Gateway

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently in the process of creating a website with AWS DynamoDB on the backend. From the frontend I call the AWS API Gateway that runs a Lambda function and then fetches the data from the DynamoDB.

Now I've defined an 'Item' object with several attributes, including a 'Tags' attribute. A single Item can have multiple Tags. Both are stored in separate DynamoDB tables and Item has a 'Tags'-column with an array of TagIDs. Each TagID links to a Tag in the Tags table.

The question is, how do I best fetch an item and their corresponding tag objects?

When I run this from the frontend, I call on the /items API that fetches the item I want. Under Tags, I get an array of TagIDs back. I want these tags as actual objects, so should I simply invoke a second API call and replace the array of TagIDs with the objects? I'm trying to find out what is best practice in this scenario.

As I'm writing this, perhaps I should edit my Lambda function that gets the items, so that it includes the Tag objects?

This is not a completely accurate representation of what I'm doing, but it should give you the right idea.

```js
function Item() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoad() {
      if (!props.isAuthenticated) {
        return;
      }
      try{
        const items = await loadItems();
        setItems(items);
        /* Should I run my secondary call here? */
      } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }
    onLoad();
  }, [props.isAuthenticated]);

  function loadItems() {
    return API.get('nh', '/items');
  }
}

Item.propTypes = {
    itemId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    category: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    tags: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
}
```

Comment: So, what happens when you run the second function? in that place you made the comment

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I haven't implemented this yet, I'm really looking for input on what the best way of doing this would be. Right now I'm thinking, where the comment currently is, create an empty array, then make an API call to /tags and filter the tags by ID, push them into the array and then replace the TagIDs on the Item with the new array that contains the Tag objects.

Comment: So, considering that you have only `isAuthenticated` as the hook dependancy, this works only as `componentDidMount` and you need those objects (items and modified tag) at that time. So what you are thinking to do sounds right now. unless there comes another problem which we cannot foresee now.

Comment: BTW I recommend clear `isAuthenticated` from dependencies and leave it as your router responsibility to redirect on un-authorized calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do this on the API level as I believe this is more of a business logic approach. The item I'm fetching should return with tags as an array of tag objects.

I need to clean it up a bit, but this is what I did.

```js
export async function main(event, context) {
    const itemParams = {
        TableName: process.env.itemsTable
    };
    const tagParams = {
        TableName: process.env.tagsTable
    };

    try {
        const itemResult = await dynamoDbLib.call('scan', itemParams);
        const tagResult = await dynamoDbLib.call('scan', tagParams);

        itemResult.Items.forEach(item => {

            /* Get tag objects per item */
            let tagObjects = [];
            item.tags.forEach(tag => {
                tagObjects.push(tagResult.Items.filter(obj => {
                    return obj.tagId === tag;
                })[0]);
            });
            item.tags = tagObjects;
        });

        return success(itemResult.Items);
    } catch(e) {
        return failure({ status: false });
    }
}
```